# Symfony 3 : add a field to a already submitted form

Tags: forms, symfony, field

after looking on other topics i haven't resolved my problem, i'm looking to add the field user_id to the form (as the user won't choose it) but symfony return me "Call to a member function addEventListener() on string"

here is my code :

```
if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, function(FormEvent $event) {
            $data = $event->getData();
            $form = $event->getForm();
            $data['user_id'] = '2';
            $event->setData($data); 
        });
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($deplacement);
        $em->flush($deplacement);

        return $this->redirectToRoute('deplacement_show', array('id' => $deplacement->getId()));
    }
```

Comment: Rather than using the FormBuilder, why don't you do `$entity->setUser($user)` in the controller before flushing, where `$user` is the user object you fetch post submit?

Answer (score 0):

Sure this is the good aproach? Maybe is better for you to write a method to update or create $deplacement, and pass 2 argoument: the $data variable from the form and the user_id, like this:

```
if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $userId = 2; 
    $formData->userId = $userId;
    $deplacement->update($formData);
    $em->persist($deplacement);
    $em->flush($deplacement);

    return $this->redirectToRoute('deplacement_show', array('id' => $deplacement->getId()));
}
```

Also I think you dont need the event listener. Why are you using it?

Comment: I don't think you need to use that event listener, but if you want you have to put that code in the FormType. probably you have found that code somewhere and you copied in the controller, but the $builder variable generaly are use in that object, the formType of the form you are using.

Comment: but i'm sure you don't need that event listener

Comment: I've update my answer with the right code, this will work.